# How to plot histogram where a country is a bin

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

I am attempting to plot a histogram where the y-axis should be the count and the x-axis (i.e. the bins) should be composed of all the countries, but I cannot seem to figure out the code.

I have tried following https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/tag/pandas/ and [How to create Histograms in Panda Python Using Specific Rows and Columns in Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710747/how-to-create-histograms-in-panda-python-using-specific-rows-and-columns-in-data), but both of those are for bar graphs and not for histograms.

```py
per_country = df.groupby(['COUNTRY'])[['TOTAL']].sum()
per_country = per_country.sort_values('TOTAL')
per_country.head()
medals_per_country['TOTAL'].plot(kind='hist')  # if hist is changed to bar, then it works, but I need a histogram and not a bar graph
```

The result should be a histogram where the x-axis includes a label for each country and the y-axis is the total for each country. Right now the bins are just based on the 'TOTAL', whereas the y-axis is the number of countries with said 'TOTAL'.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Can you create some sample data?

Comment: Are you sure you want a histogram? According to this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram a histogram requires numerical data also on the x-axis. I think what you want is a density plot or am I wrong?

Comment: what is the reason for not using `plot(kind='bar')`? It seems to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I feel as though I might be reading the question wrong.